# Use long-type id in LinkedList

Tags: java

I want to use **LinkedList** in my class **OpenList**, but I using id of **long**-type. How can I use     **LinkedList** with long **id**. I asking about really **long id**, `not (int) my_long_id`

```
List.get(id)
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are talking about. What is id of a LinkedList?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Index

Comment: Are you saying you have more than 2 billion entries in your LinkedList, and you want to access elements by index?!

Comment: @NPE it seems, that author asks exactly about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it is impossible to do what you wand with interface `List` (and all its inheritances), because `List` interface declares, that index of its elements can be only of type `int`.
If you want to have `long` type for indexing elements in your `List`, you have to create new interface (i.e. `LongList`) and create new class implementation of `LinkedList` (i.e. `LongLinkedList`), since you have sources of original `LinkedList` class.